# How can I instantiate a class from a dll in C++?

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport

I am writing an API for plugin developers so that they can access the SDK of an application through my API. My API offers a macro and abstract class* in a header file that plugin-devs must include to inherit from the abstract base class and implement the necessary functions (*see code below).

As far as research on the issue at hand, I've read through many MSDN and stackoverflow articles and found these most relevant:

- [COM/ATL stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/introduction-to-com-and-atl?view=vs-2019)
- [An article in C# similar to what I'm trying to do in C++ using reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126716/instantiate-plugin-class-in-a-dll)
- [This article on why C++ doesn't have reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359237/why-does-c-not-have-reflection)
- and tons of similarly titled articles asking about calling functions from a DLL

This question is about getting an instance of an inherited abstract class/interface that you're expecting plugin developer to implement when they create their `.dll` files.

Perhaps my methodology is incorrect and I've gone down a rabbit hole, but something like Reflections and/or COM seems what I should be doing... only COM seems overkill for this operation as the application will be running client side. This article on [C++/CLI Reflections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/reflection-cpp-cli?view=vs-2019#implement) seemed promising, but I'm working in Visual Studio with C++17.

At the highest level, the intended behavior is:

1. `API.dll` loads directory of plugins (e.g. `plugin/plugin1.dll` and
   `plugin/plugin2.dll`)
2. `API.dll` creates singleton instance of the plugin through the abstract class' `getPlugin()`
3. Call the other methods implemented by the plugin, of notable interest is `load()`

So here's some background setup information about the API's usage by the plugin developers. The API offers a header to the devs for the interface/abstract class and the methods to create singletons in a macro.

**API's: *baseplugin.hpp***

```cpp
#ifdef BUILDINGAPI
#define PLUGINIMPORT 
#define PLUGINEXPORT  __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define PLUGINIMPORT  __declspec(dllimport)
#define PLUGINEXPORT  __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

// Long macro defined here for creating/deleting singleton
#define PLUGIN(classType)                                           \
static std::shared_ptr<classType> singleton;                        \
extern "C" {                                                        \
    PLUGINEXPORT uintptr_t getPlugin()                                  \
    {                                                               \
        if(!singleton) {                                            \
            singleton = std::shared_ptr<classType>(new classType());\
        }                                                           \
        return reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&singleton);        \
    }                                                               \
    PLUGINEXPORT void erasePlugin() {                               \
        if(singleton)                                               \
            singleton = nullptr;                                    \
      }                                                             \
}

// Abstract class defined here:

class PLUGINEXPORT baseplugin
{
public:
    virtual void load() = 0;
    virtual void unload() = 0;
};
```

So a plugin developer can quickly create a plugin using:

**Plugin's: *plugin1.hpp***

```
class plugin1: public baseplugin
{
public:
    virtual void load();
    virtual void unload();
// other useful plugin methods/vars
}
```

**Plugin's: *plugin1.cpp***

```
PLUGIN(plugin1) // This creates getPlugin() and erasePlugin()
void plugin1::load() {
// do stuff
}
void plugin1::unload() {
// do stuff
}
// other functions
```

Now I'm left with loading the coding/building the `API.dll` to load a directory of plugin .dlls. Here's my current code for this, which I realize isn't going to work do to not know the RTTI:

**API's: dllmain.cpp**

```
typedef uintptr_t(*pFunc)();
HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("plugin1.dll"));
if (hinstLib != NULL) {
    FARPROC ProcAdd = GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "getPlugin"); // address to singeleton function
    // If the function address is valid, call the function.  
    if (NULL != ProcAdd) {
        pFunc pPluginSingleton = (pFunc) ProcAdd;
        baseplugin* plugin1Singleton = (baseplugin*) pPluginSingleton(); // THIS LINE WORKS, I GET A POINTER TO A SINGLETON
        plugin1Singleton->load(); // THIS CRASHES!!!!
```

It may be worth noting here that building the `API.dll` with the code for `plugin1.dll` works as expected. I'm now testing/figuring out how to have plugins types loaded at runtime. I have verified that I'm able to get the pointer to the singleton with a debugger, but I crash when trying to run the load method after casting it to the abstract class:
`0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x80B1CCDC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to implement a plugin API is with the help of the [boost::dll](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html). It provides some helpfull tools for implementing a plugin mechanism. There is, for example, the [Factory method in plugin](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html#boost_dll.tutorial.factory_method_in_plugin).

Comment: It turns out my implementation of a plugin architecture for the API is correct. It was really my call to the plugin1's load() function that was the issue. I'm accepting this answer as it provided the boost::dll as reference to show that I was indeed using an interface properly and removed any doubt. I will say there's not really a need for the reinterpret_cast though.

Answer (score 1):

Your application knows nothing about concrete types defined in plugins. The only things it can operate on are classes defined in your application. Each plugin needs to provide a factory method that creates an instance of a concrete type defined in the plugin, and return a pointer to an abstract class defined in your application. Something like this defined in `Plugin1.dll`:

```
baseplugin* PLUGINEXPORT create_plugin()
{
    return new plugin1;
}
```

In your application you dynamically load `Plugin1.dll`, get address of `create_plugin` function and call it to get an instance of `plugin1` class as a pointer to `baseplugin` abstract class.

Comment: Is this not what my macro is doing? I realized I have a typo in my original question on the macro, where `DLLIMPORT` is meant to be `PLUGINEXPORT`, I'll edit it now. In either case, the macro, `PLUGIN(plugin1)` in `Plugin1.cpp` defines `getPlugin()` which returns a pointer to a singleton instance as `uintptr_t`. In the final code snippet, I try casting this to baseplugin* and using it-- but this crashes the application see: `plugin1Singleton->load();`